# React native Release Apk Building Error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'll build my react native project it build success, but whenever i will try to build release Apk It's give error

```
error: uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file..
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the known [issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3097) of `react-navigation` library. As a workaround you need to add this line to `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

and clean all previous build files using:

```
./gradlew clean
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

in your gradle.properties file add these lines

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Comment: @AkshayItaliya  yes it is. Still not found any permanent solution for this